# change two images in php

Tags: php

EDIT:
I have to images (or two strings) on a page. One on the left and the other on the right side. I want them to randomly switch their position when refreshing the site. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: The PHP function for this is called [`imagerotate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php). The manual page has a full example.

Comment: yes, you can write text into an image using [`imagettftext()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) and rotate that

Comment: @pekka - Sorry but try to understand question first.

Comment: @RIKY That's a bit rich coming from somebody with your question history. Anyway, the question was worded differently originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$image1 = echo "<img src='image_path'>";
$image2 = echo "<img src='image_path'>";

if(rand(0,1)==0){
   $image3 = $image1;
   $image1 = $image2;
   $image2 = $image3;
 }

<div style="float:right">$image1</div>
<div style="float:left">$image2</div>
```

Comment: Why not just `rand(0, 1)` and drop the modulus?

Comment: thanks. just a little typo in the if, it should be: $image3 = $image2; $image2 = $image1; $image1 = $image3; Like JohnP says, I use if(rand(0,1)==0){...}

Answer (score 0):

Use imagerotate() and rand() functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [imagerotate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) for this thing. The documentation has this simple example:

```
<?php
// File and rotation
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$degrees = 180;

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

// Output
imagejpeg($rotate);
```

So, just write a script that takes a filename as a parameter (via $_GET) and then rotate it by a random degree (use [rand](http://php.net/rand) for this). Then just change your image link to `rotator.php?file=first.jpg`.

Another option is to do the rotation with CSS3 and JavaScript. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685430/rotate-two-images-in-php) for more information on rotating with CSS3.

Comment: I think we both misunderstood, she meant "switch positions"